# Global solution of IVP.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

My question is as follows :

Let $f$ and $g$ are positive continuous functions on $\mathbb R$ with $g\leq f$ everywhere. Assume that IVP $$x’=f(x), x(0)=0$$  has a solution defined on all of $\mathbb R$, then prove that the IVP $$x’=g(x), x(0)=0$$ also has a solution defined on all of $\mathbb R$.  I am thinking as follows::

As first IVP has a solution which does not blow up in finite time and because $g\leq f$ everywhere, hence second IVP solution does not have possibility to blow up in finite time. Therefore,  second IVP also have a solution defined on all of $\mathbb R$. Am I correct? Thank you.

Comment: @JeanMarie IVP means [Initial Value Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_value_problem), it's an ODE with a specified initial condition. What we would call a Cauchy problem in France.

Comment: @Bruno B Thanks ! It's clear now !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea is correct. You can formalize your idea as follows: Let $f,g \in C(\mathbb{R},(0,\infty))$ with $g \le f$, and let $x:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $y:(\omega_-,\omega_+) \to \mathbb{R}$ be the solutions of $x'(t)=f(x(t)), x(0)=0$ and $y'(t)=g(y(t)),y(0)=0$, respectively, with $y$ nonextendable. The functions $x,y$ are increasing, and by the method for ODEs of separate variables the solutions are unique and
$$
\int_0^{x(t)} \frac{1}{f(s)} ds = t = \int_0^{y(t)} \frac{1}{g(s)} ds  \quad (t \in (\omega_-,\omega_+)).
$$
Since $1/f \le 1/g$ we get $0\le y(t) \le x(t)$ $(t \in [0,\omega_+))$ and $x(t) \le y(t) \le 0$ $(t \in (\omega_-,0])$. Thus, there is no blow up of $y$ in finite time, neither to the left nor to the right. So $\omega_-=-\infty$ and $\omega_+=\infty$.